# Way to provide complex unique restriction

Tags: sobject, custom-index

Let's say we have custom object with 2 key fields. How can I provide complex unique index to avoid interactive inserting records with the same values in this fields?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a third field with a unique index, then set the value in this field using the other two fields via Process Builder, trigger, etc. The system will automatically prevent duplicates based on this index.